# how to determine if a number is a smart number in java?

Tags: java, arrays

I have this question I am trying to solve. I have tried coding for the past 4 hours.

> An integer is defined to be a Smart number if it is an element in the infinite sequence
>   1, 2, 4, 7, 11, 16 …
>   Note that 2-1=1, 4-2=2, 7-4=3, 11-7=4, 16-11=5 so for k>1, the kth element of the sequence is equal to the k-1th element + k-1. For example, for k=6, 16 is the kth element and is equal to 11 (the k-1th element) + 5 ( k-1).
>       Write function named isSmart that returns 1 if its argument is a Smart number, otherwise it returns 0. So isSmart(11) returns 1, isSmart(22) returns 1 and isSmart(8) returns 0

I have tried the following code to

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class IsSmart {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int x = isSmart(11);
        System.out.println(x);
    }

    public static int isSmart(int n) {
        int[] y = new int[n];
        int j = 0;

        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            y[j] = i;
            j++;
        }

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(y));

        for (int i = 0; i <= y.length; i++) {
            int diff = 0;
            y[j] = y[i+1] - y[i] ;
            y[i] = diff;
        }

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(y));

        for (int i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
            if(n == y[i])
                return 1;
        }

        return 0;
    }
}
```

When I test it with 11 it is giving me 0 but it shouldn't. Any idea how to correct my mistakes?

Comment: have you debugged your code?

Comment: yeah I have but couldn't seem to locate the error

Comment: In the 2nd `for` loop you are reading/writing past the end of the array.

Comment: Hint. when you dont understand what your code is doing: add print statements. Respectively: "run" the code manually, with a pen and a piece of paper.

Comment: Hint: you are printing the content of the `y` array - i'm pretty sure the values at the second `println` are not what you expect...

Comment: You are overcomplicating this. Just create a variable for the smart number (start at 1) and one for the increment (also 1). Then in a loop, calculate the next smart number. If equal to `n` return true. If greater than `n` return false. Else calculate next smart number. Example: https://ideone.com/Ink0J2

Comment: @JohnnyMopp your algorithm seems to be a little more complicated to me since I am a beginner in java could you give me the code in the answer section please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you don't need to build an array:

```
public static int isSmart(int n) {
    int smart = 1;
    for (int i = 1; smart < n; i++) {
        smart = smart + i;
    }
    return smart == n ? 1 : 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It can be done in a simpler way as follows

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public class IsSmart {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x = isSmart(11);
        System.out.println("Ans: "+x);
    }

    public static int isSmart(int n) {

         //------------ CHECK THIS LOGIC ------------//
        int[] y = new int[n];
        int diff = 1;

        for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
            y[0] =1;
            y[i] = diff + y[i-1];
            diff++;
        }
       //------------ CHECK THIS LOGIC ------------//

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(y));
        for (int i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
            if(n == y[i])
                return 1;
        }

        return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One of the problems is the way that your populating your array.

The array can be populated as such

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  y[i] = (i == 0) ? 1 : y[i - 1] + i;
}
```

The overall application of the function `isSmart` can be simplified to:

```
public static int isSmart(int n) {
  int[] array = new int[n];

  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    array[i] = (i == 0) ? 1 : array[i - 1] + i; 
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] == n) return 1;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a naive way to think of it to get you started - you need to fill out the while() loop. The important thing to notice is that:

**The next value of the sequence will be the number of items in the sequence + the last item in the sequence.**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(isSmart(11));
    }

    public static int isSmart(int n) {
        ArrayList<Integer> sequence = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        // Start with 1 in the ArrayList
        sequence.add(1);

        // You need to keep track of the index, as well as
        // the next value you're going to add to your list
        int index = 1; // or number of elements in the sequence
        int nextVal = 1;

        while (nextVal < n) {
            // Three things need to happen in here:

            // 1) set nextVal equal to the sum of the current index + the value at the *previous* index

            // 2) add nextVal to the ArrayList

            // 3) incriment index by 1
        }

        // Now you can check to see if your ArrayList contains n (is Smart)
        if (sequence.contains(n)) { return 1; }

        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to solve this problem without the help of collections in java simply by using arrays and loops and methods

Answer (score 1):

*First think of a mathematical solution.*

Smart numbers form a sequence:

- a<sub>0</sub> = 1
- a<sub>n+1</sub> = n + a<sub>n</sub>

This gives a function for smart numbers:

- f(x) = ax² + bx + c
- f(x + 1) = f(x) + x = ...

So the problem is to find for a given y a matching x.
You can do this by a binary search.

```
int isSmart(int n) {
    int xlow = 1;
    int xhigh = n; // Exclusive. For n == 0 return 1.
    while (xlow < xhigh) {
        int x = (xlow + xhigh)/2;
        int y = f(x);
        if (y == n) {
            return 1;
        }
        if (y < n) {
            xlow = x + 1;
        } else {
            xhigh = x;
        }
    }
    return 0; 
}
```

Yet smarter would be to use the solution for x and look whether it is an integer:

```
ax² + bx + c' = 0 where c' = c - n
x = ...
```

Comment: for this code to work I need to define f(x) in a separate method and call it in `isSmart(int n)` what should f(x) be like?

Comment: It should be ax² + bx + c. It would be your task to find the formula, the _a_, _b_, and _c_. That is simple enough. Then you should be able to find the solution for ax² + bx + c' = 0, and check that b²-4ac is a square (taking the square root with Math.sqrt) and such.

Comment: It is a bit much, but whereas a loop is like counting on ones fingers, a math solution is not only faster, it is more intelligent. Think of `isSmart(f(1000))`.

Comment: so the quadratic function should map 1000 to its smart number right?

Comment: One could simply do `isSmart(100_000)` but around that number many calls will return 0, with `isSmart(f(1000))` one would expect 1.

Comment: [Then](https://www.purplemath.com/modules/quadform.htm) isSmart(n) = "8n-7 is a square"; `{ int r = (int)Math.sqrt(n).round(); return r*r == n ? 1 : 0; }`. (I can give this solution as you have to explain the entire math.)

Comment: the above formula works for every smart number guess `n = 8n-7` does the trick

Comment: Yes I intended `Math.sqrt(8*n-7)`

Answer (score 1):

I was playing around with this and I noticed something.  The smart numbers are

`1    2    4    7    11    16    22    29  ...`

If you subtract one you get

`0    1    3    6    10    15    21    28 ...`
`0    1    2    3     4     5     6     7 ...` 
The above sequence happens to be the sum of the first n numbers starting with `0` which is 
 `n*(n+1)/2`.  So add `1` to that and you get a smart number.

Since `n` and `n+1` are next door to each other  you can derive them by reversing the process.

Take `29`, subtract `1 = 28, * 2 = 56`.  The `sqrt(56)` rounded up is 8. So the `8th` smart number (counting from 0) is `29`.

Using that information you can detect a smart number without a loop by simply reversing the process.

```
    public static int isSmart(int v) {
        int vv = (v-1)*2;
        int sq = (int)Math.sqrt(vv);
        int chk = (sq*(sq+1))/2 + 1;
        return (chk == v) ? 1 : 0;
    }
```

Using a version which supports `longs` have verified this against the iterative process from `1 to 10,000,000,000`.

Comment: I don't understand what the for loop and the return statement is doing. The code looks really simple and It is working fine.